# Kotlin Int to Byte Conversion

Tags: arrays, sockets, kotlin, binary, outputstream

What is the Kotlin 1.5 command to convert a 16 bit integer to a Byte of length 2? Secondary problem is that outputstream needs a string at the end so it can convert with toByteArray()

```
# Original Python Code
...
i = int((2**16-1)*ratio) # 16 bit int
i.to_bytes(2, byteorder='big')
output = (i).to_bytes(2, byteorder='big') 


# Kotlin Code so far
var i = ((2.0.pow(16) - 1) * ratio).toInt() // Convert to 16 bit Integer
print("16 bit Int: " + i)
output = .....

....
...
val outputStream: OutputStream = socket.getOutputStream()
outputStream.write(output.toByteArray()) // write requires ByteArray for some reason
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple math, so it is probably the best to calculate manually and define as an extension function:

```
fun Int.to2ByteArray() : ByteArray = byteArrayOf(toByte(), shr(8).toByte())
```

Then you can use it:

```
output = i.to2ByteArray()
outputStream.write(output)
```

Note, this function writes the integer in little-endian. If you need big-endian the just reverse the order of items in the array. You can also add some min/max checks if you need them.

Also, if you only need 16-bit values then you can consider using `Short` or `UShort` instead of `Int`. It doesn't change much regarding the memory usage, but it could be a cleaner approach - we could name our extension just `toByArray()` and we would not need min/max checks.

Comment: shr function does not work with Short or UShort so it needs another conversion in the function. Are you sure using them could be cleaner with the extra conversion?

Comment: Yes, I think so. It doesn't matter that much what's inside the function - it's implementation details. More important is the type safety and that the caller of the function knows what is expected as an input